# solr sorting parent with child field. ignoring parent with no child values

Tags: solr

I am using **Solr 6.6**,  we have a parent document which has a child document. We are sorting the parent with field in child. Sorting works fine, but when there is no child field for a parent, ascending sorting puts those on top.

I tried by putting `sortMissingLast` as `true` on all fields in child, but it doesn't work.

Example of the data:

```
[
  {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "product"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "type": "product",
    "childDocuments": [
      {
        "field1": 1,
        "field2": 2,
        "field3": 3,
        "type": "price"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "type": "product"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "type": "product"
  }
]
```

Comment: could you show an example of the query/data?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response too much occupied.
example data
{
        "id":"2",
 "type":"product"},
      {
        "id":"3",
 "type":"product",
        "_childDocuments_":[
        {
          "field1":1,
          "field2":2,
          "field3":3,
          "type":"price"}]
      },
      {
        "id":"4",
 "type":"product"
      },
      {
        "id":"6",
 "type":"product"
      }
}

Comment: If you see here, id 2 doesn't have child documents but 3 has.. when i sort based on the child field and in ascending, i get empty child documents at top

Comment: @Mysterion is this enough ?

Comment: this is good addition, could you please add query that you're doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did it like below
{!parent which=type:parent score=max v='+type:child {!func}sortField'}
when sorting by descending the above will go directly in sort=
when sorting by ascending the above will be copied to a substitute like $computefield and added to the query. Then use def function for the computefield to have a default value like 99999